# Como alterar conteúdo dentro da div com Ajax/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Aqui lista todos os registros que ao clicar em editar abre um modal com valor da descrição.

```
<?php foreach ($beneficios as $v): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $v->id; ?></td>
                            <td class='descricao'><?= $v->descricao; ?></td>
                            <td class="actions actions-fade">
                                <a data-toggle="modal" id="<?= $v->id; ?>" class="beneficio" data-target="#<?= $v->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="<?= $v->id; ?>" class="delete-row deletar-beneficio"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Como eu faço para alterar o conteúdo da td que tem a classe descricao? Colocando nela o mesmo conteúdo que o ajax está recebendo, veja:

```
function alterarBeneficio(dados) {
    $.ajax({
        url: path + 'administrador/alterarBeneficio',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'dados': dados},
        success: function (response) {
            if (parseInt(response) === 1) {

                // Preciso colocar uma função aqui que altere o conteudo da TD, colocando o conteudo que foi passado na variavel dados, é possivel?

                $(".alterado").show(500);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".alterado").fadeOut(1000);
                }, 3000);
            } else {
                console.log('ocorreu um erro!');
            }
        },
        error: function (erro, er) {
            console.log(erro, er);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar dois métodos em jQuery:

**.text**
`$('td.descricao').text('aqui vai o conteudo text');`

**.html**
`$('td.descricao').html('<p>Aqui vai seu <strong>HTML</strong></p>');`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
debugger;
  $('td.descricao').text('aqui vai o conteudo text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="descricao">oi</td>
    <td>TOOOOOO</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Eu coloquei esse código  $('td .descricao').text('Testandooooo');   porém não altera nenhum conteúdo ao dar sucesso :/

Comment: @ViniciusAquino desculpe, coloquei o selector separado, na verdade é junto `td.descricao` ao inves de `td .descricao` - atualizei a resposta

Comment: Agora foi, porém ele altera o conteudo de todas as td, como eu posso fazer com que altere apenas a td que o cara selecionou?

Comment: coloca o codigo todo, onde voce dispara esse evento? por um button? onde esse button fica no html

Comment: Eu disparo o evento no submit que fica dentro de um modal, coloquei todo o código aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/etn8dpnz/

Comment: vc tem o id no seu modal certo? ou entao na `response` pq na mesma td que voce tem a classe `descricao`, voce tb tem o `id` nela, entao voce usa ele como selector ex.
`$('#' + response.id).text('text');`

Comment: Eu estou tentando retornar o id mas dá undefined: console.log(response.id);

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56377/discussion-between-andrepaulo-and-vinicius-aquino).